# Switching Active Sheets and Counting Rows

Tags: vba, excel

I am checking the row count on sheet 1 and comparing that to the count on sheet 2 to confirm all rows on sheet 1 are on sheet 2.

First, I select sheet 1 to be active then get count for rows that have data

Second, I switch the active sheet to sheet 2.  Sheet 2 contains rows that have data but sheet 1 and sheet 2 are not equal in rows that contain data.

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
num = Application.WorsheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2").Select
num2 = Application.WorsheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))
```

The problem is that every time I get the value for *num2*, it's always equal to *num* and I know this is not true.  If I manually check the *countA(A1:A100)*, I get a value that would prove *num != num2*.  My guess is that even though I'm switching to a new active sheet, the num2 calculation is still being determined based on Sheet 1.  Is that true?  Is there some glaring problem with my code?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: How many rows do you have? What are `num` and `num2` declared as? As an aside, I would avoid doing `Select` at all as it is an unnecessary drain on resources. You can achieve the same thing by doing `num = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))`

Comment: There is a typo error in "Worksheet"

Comment: can you show the data sets (or a sample)? I can't reproduce the issue. Also, are the rows contiguous on each sheet? There's another method if so.

Comment: copy/paste error Karthick....the code was correct thought for spelling.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `Select` here. Also, try avoid them as much as possible.

So all you need is to qualify the range with its sheet.

```
num = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:A"))

num2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"))
```

Comment: OPs code with select worked on my machine, so I'm not sure that this is an answer entirely, but it is a very good suggestion to avoid using `Select` or `Activate` and instead reference the objects directly.

Comment: second line should be `num2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A"))` doesn't let me to edit

Comment: thank you cyboashu.  I have heard that using the "switching" code as I did tends to slow down the code but from a logic perspective, how is my code different from yours?  Mine SHOULD switch as yours did and work as desired but did not however yours did work as I would intend.  What is the difference between our methods?